# Perforce: How can I get files "as of" a date or revision from before a branch action?

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

Consider the following revisions of a file:

```
branch                   -1---2---
                        /               
                       /                
main   100--101-102--103---104---
```

I am currently in my branch and the file is synced to revision 2. I know that p4 has kept the history of the file, because I used merge and not copy, and indeed the history shows revisions previous to 103 (inclusive) when I look at the history of the file and check the option "Follow branch actions".

I would like to roll it back to revision 103 or before. Is this possible?

Answers for p4v preferred, but I'll take command line statements if that's the only way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "roll it back"? Do you just want to get the older version on your laptop, so you can build it and test it, etc.? Or do you want to undo the changes made by revision 2 in your branch, so that other users of your branch will not see that change when they sync the branch?

Comment: Hi, I just mean to get the older version on my laptop.

Comment: Then do `p4 sync //path/to/the/file#103` to sync revision 103 to your laptop. In P4V, you can do that by right-clicking on the file and using 'Get Revision' (rather than 'Get Latest Revision'), and filling in the revision 103 in the dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `copy` command is the best way of doing this:

```
p4 copy main#103 branch
```

Another option would be to use `integ -f`:

```
p4 integ -f main#103 branch
p4 resolve -at
```

One benefit of `copy` is that if you're doing this across a bunch of files (e.g. `main/...@2018/01/01` to get all of `main` as of Jan 1) and some of them are already identical to the rev you're copying from because they haven't changed in that time, `copy` will leave them alone, which makes the result less noisy.